# want to startup new vagrant project but old one keeps starting

Tags: laravel, vagrant

I'm new to laravel/homestead/vagrant and really struggling.  I have managed to download and run a demo program.  I copied the demo folder to a new name and now want to get the copy running instead of the original, so that I can gradually start converting it into the program I want.

I modified the Homestead.yaml file in the new folder so the folders section looks like this:

```
folders:
    - map: ~/LaravelProjects/MedAverter
      to: /home/vagrant/code

sites:
    - map: homestead.test
      to: /home/vagrant/code/public
```

Then I suspend the running box, cd to the new folder, and do

```
vagrant up
```

But when I do

```
vagrant global-status
```

it shows the old one running, not the new one.

```
$ vagrant global-status
id       name      provider   state   directory
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
cd58265  homestead virtualbox running C:/Users/greg/LaravelProjects/travel-planet-crud
```

EDIT: 
Then I suspended that instance, and reloaded the new instance.

```
    greg@DELL-DESKTOP MINGW64 ~/LaravelProjects/MedAverter (master)
    $ vagrant suspend
    ==> homestead: Saving VM state and suspending execution...

    greg@DELL-DESKTOP MINGW64 ~/LaravelProjects/MedAverter (master)
    $ vagrant global-status
    id       name      provider   state  directory
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    cd58265  homestead virtualbox saved  C:/Users/greg/LaravelProjects/travel-planet-crud
$ vagrant reload --provision
==> homestead: Discarding saved state of VM...
==> homestead: Checking if box 'laravel/homestead' version '9.2.2-alpha1' is up to date...

greg@DELL-DESKTOP MINGW64 ~/LaravelProjects/MedAverter (master)
$ vagrant global-status
id       name      provider   state   directory
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
cd58265  homestead virtualbox running C:/Users/greg/LaravelProjects/travel-planet-crud
```

So you see, even though I'm in the new instance folder, something is still pointing it back to the old instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try to run `vagrant reload --provision` 
It will restart your vagrant and apply any changes that you made.

Comment: I edited my post to include the reload command you suggested.  Even though status still shows old program running, I know it is the new one actually running since I made some changes to the blade file in the new folder and can see those changes when I put "homestead.test" in the browser.  Strange system.